# How to interpret the function type in Haskell?

Tags: function, haskell

My code is the following

```
data Tree a = Leaf a | Node (Tree a) (Tree a) 
    deriving (Show)
f x = x + 1
myTree = Node (Node (Leaf 2) (Leaf 3)) (Leaf 4)
maptree f (Leaf a)= Leaf (f a)
maptree f (Node xl xr ) = Node (maptree f xl) (maptree f xr)
```

which can add one to the Leaf element in the tree.

I further look at the function type which are

```
*Main> let maptree f (Leaf a)= Leaf (f a) 
maptree :: (t -> a) -> Tree t -> Tree a 

*Main> let maptree f (Node  xl xr ) = Node (maptree f xl) (maptree f xr) 
maptree :: t -> Tree t1 -> Tree a
```

What do t, a, and t1 mean over here? Is there any reference that I can read for those stuffs?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We'll start with the first signature:

```
(t -> a) -> Tree t -> Tree a
```

This essentially says, "Given a function that takes something of type `t` and produces an `a` and also a `Tree` containing items of type `t`, produce a `Tree` containing elements of type `a`.

`t` and `a` are completely arbitrary names that GHCi generated; we could have easily said:

```
(originalType -> newType) -> Tree originalType -> Tree newType
```

Although most programmers would write:

```
(a -> b) -> Tree a -> Tree b
```

Now, the second signature:

```
t -> Tree t1 -> Tree a
```

This signature's strange because, like Hammar pointed out, the two `maptree` definitions you wrote in GHCi are completely independent.  So let's look at the second definition all by itself:

```
maptree f (Node xl xr) = Node (maptree f xl) (maptree f xr)
```

Here, the type of `f` does not matter as you don't apply it to any arguments and you only pass it to `maptree`, which recursively doesn't care what type `f` is.  So let's give `f` type `t`, as it doesn't matter.

Now, similarly, there's no constraint on `xl` and `xr`, as they are only passed to `maptree` which doesn't know their types except that it should be a `Tree`.  Thus, we might as well call their type `Tree t1`.

We know this function will return a `Tree` because of the `Node` constructor, but the previous two types we looked at have no bearing on the type of elements in the tree, so we may as well call it `Tree a`.

As an example, let's see what happens when we expand the following:

```
maptree True (Node (Leaf 0) (Leaf 1))
= Node (maptree True (Leaf 0)) (maptree True (Leaf 1))
```

Which then fails because there's no way for `maptree` to expand a `Leaf` in this case.

However, the types work out:

```
True                   :: t
Node (Leaf 0) (Leaf 1) :: Tree t1
0                      :: t1
1                      :: t1
```

So that signature was very odd, but it does make sense.  Remember to not overwrite definitions, I guess.

Answer (score 3):

Identifiers beginning with a lower case letter, like `t`, `a` and `t1`, are *type variables* when used in a type context. They are placeholders which can be specialized to any type. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6929305/good-tutorial-for-haskell-type-signatures/6930098#6930098) for more information on how to read type signatures.

Also note that in GHCi, your example will first define one function which only handles the `Leaf` case, and then replace it with another which only handles the `Node` case, unlike in Haskell source files where they will be two cases of the same function. To specify multiple equations for a function in GHCi, separate them with a semicolon:

```
*Main> let maptree f (Leaf a) = Leaf (f a); maptree f (Node xl xr) = Node (maptree f xl) (maptree f xr)
```

or use multiline mode:

```
*Main> :{
*Main| let maptree f (Leaf a) = Leaf (f a)
*Main|     maptree f (Node xl xr) = Node (maptree f xl) (maptree f xr)
*Main| :}
```

Comment: The second method gives me a error, parse error on input

    *Main> :{
    *Main| let maptree f (Leaf a) = Leaf (f a)
    *Main|     maptree f (Node xl xr) = Node (maptree f xl) (maptree f xr)
    *Main| :}

    <interactive>:1:62: parse error on input `='
Thanks.

Comment: @Dong-BangTsai: Did you indent the second equation for `maptree` to line up with the first one as I did in the example?

Comment: +1 for noting multiline-mode - I didn't know that - very useful.

Comment: Don't copy and paste the `Main*|`'s.  GHCi puts those in to let you know you are still in multi-line mode.